# How to Bind a Source to an entity without objects

Tags: c#, devexpress, entity-framework-6

Sorry I don't know how to explain the question in the title...

In design mode, when I bind a BindingSource to an entity class the source is without objects (not null).
I want to do the same in runtime mode; bind to the same type or w/e...

```
BindingSource.DataSource = new entity(); // doesn't work because it's not clear
BindingSource.DataSource = new EntityCollection<entity>() //it's clear, but is not the original type
```

What I really want to do is something like this:
For my tables Sales and SaleDetails

```
if (Sales.Count > 0)
   -bind to collection or something
else
   -bind to the original type (the one in design mode)
```

(bind to null doesn't work, because of binding errors... also if I use bindingSource.Clear() it doesn't work because when I call ctx.Savechanges() it deletes all entities

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start from using the [Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16633). It provides simple and intuitive way to bind the Grid control to any data source. For example with Entity Framework data source you can bind the GridControl directly to EF data source, via the BindingSource component, or with using special data-binding components provided by DevExpress, to perform binding in [synchronous](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398) or [asynchronous](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8893) manner, with using the [parallel data-processing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressDataPLinqPLinqInstantFeedbackSourcetopic) or without it.

According to this wizard, the BindingSource-based approach will looks as follows:

```
// This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
// Instantiate a new DBContext
NorthwindEntities dbContext = new NorthwindEntities();
// Call the Load method to get the data for the given DbSet from the database.
dbContext.Orders.Load();
// This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
bindingSource.DataSource = dbContext.Orders.Local.ToBindingList();
```

It also generates the following line within the `InitializeComponent()` method to provide a capability to manage all the GridControl's design-time settings:

```
BindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Entity)
```

Comment: Hi, im using ObjectContext... i have been trying to do the same with ObjectContext, but it says there is no available datasource... Do yout know what is the original Entity type used while binding in design mode cuz i want the same type in runtime but i cant find a way.

Comment: For design time please try the `BindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Entity)`. At run-time use the approach I mentioned in my answer. Or upgrade to the latest version of EF(DbContext)

Comment: BindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Entity) !!! Excellent, thats what i wanted, now i can validate all my forms correctly !!! thank you